# Creating a single file WCF for testing IIS setup

Tags: wcf, iis-6

Is it possible to create a single .svc file (WCF Service) that I can upload to my server and test if it correctly handles WCF files? i.e. it is configured to host WCF services.

(I have a IIS6 box that I have to test)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use inline coding in your svc file:

```
%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyService.MyService" %>
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace MyService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int MyMethod(int x, int y);
    }

    public class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public int MyMethod(int x, int y)
        {
            return ((x + y) * 2);
        }
    }
}
```

But you will need also a web.config file and a virtual directory configured on your web server:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" />
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService.MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IMyService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

But basically if your web server has IIS 6.0 and .NET 3.0 installed then you should have no problems running WCF services on it.